# How to call on functions within a function

Tags: c, function

I have written a code using some functions. In the function getType the user is asked for input, jf the input is v or V the function getHeight should be run followed by the function vArea. If the input is h or H the function hArea should be run. If there is any other input the code should display "invalid input" and then return to the function getType and ask the user for input again.

I need the value calculated by either hArea or vArea to be assigned to the function getType so I can then use this value in the main function to solve an equation. the code I have written is not working this is what the function getType looks like:

```c
double getType()
{
    char type;
    double getType, d, h;

    printf("\nEnter wind turbine type (v or h):");
    scanf("%c", &type);

    if (type == 'v' || type == 'V')
    {
        getHeight();
        vArea(d, h);
    }
    else if (type == 'h' || type == 'H')
    {
        hArea(d);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid input!");
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
            return getType;
    }
    return type;
}
```

Do you see any errors that need fixing?

Comment: Perhaps you need to read about "*How to call a function, have it return a value as result to the caller and have this result be assigned to something inside the caller?*"? I think a C primer would help.

Comment: To summarise: There is a lot unclear with your question as well with your code, and probably wrong as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy brother just do this, change your function prototype to this.

```
double getType(double d, double h);
```

You definition where you are calling getType function to this.

```
getType(d,h);
```

Lastly in function declaration

```
double getType(double d, double h)
{
double d1,h1;
d1=d;
h1=h1;

/*then rest of your code*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not look quiet right, the "getType" you declared is a double, and how you invoked it (if my understanding is correct) is also not right, since "return getType" would only return this double, which is uninitialized. 
To achieve your purpose, I would recommend you to restructure your function, simply to do the following:
`function()`

```c
int function() {
    char type;
    printf("\nEnter wind turbine type (v or h):");
    scanf("%c", &type);
    while(type != 'v' || type |= 'h' .... )
    {
        printf("\n Invalid input, please Enter wind turbine type (v or h):");
        scanf("%c", &type);
    }

    // do the actual function here
}
```

Comment: You might like to rethink this statement: `while(type != 'v' || type |= 'h' .... )`

Answer (score 1):

I had seen other thing that look unusual to me:

1. `while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)` In this variable c is declared as integer type just above this statement and you are comparing it with character type, you might get trouble here. Change variable `c` type character.
2. In else part your are returning `getType` variable with is initialized as double but not assigned any value.
3. Similarly no value is assigned to `d` and `h` variable in your code and your are send them as a argument in you `vArea` function. Please take care of that as well.
4. Make sure your `getchar()` function must be returning a single character.

Comment: i fixed number 1 and 2. In regards to 3, d and h are equal to functions that are assigned a value in the main function, i am sending them in the vArea function in order for that value to be used in the function which looks like this ``` double vArea(double d, double h)
{
double vArea;
vArea = (pi*d*h);
return vArea;
} ``` the problem i am having is that I'm not sure if the functions vArea and hArea are being called on properly in the if and else if statements and hence when i printf the value for the function getType it is incorrect.

Comment: bro if you are initializing them n your main function you should pass the as an argument in getType function. Then copy those value in your local d and h variable.

Comment: in the main function i am initialising d and h. i need the getType function to run either the vArea or hArea function depending on the input in which will then calculate the area within the area functions if you get me.

Comment: i getting you bro but i am saying in vArea function you are sending d and h arguments whose value is defined in main function but those variables are not the part of d and h until you hadn't pass them to your function. A local variable has its value in the function it is defined not in other function until you had passed it to other function.

Comment: yeah bro i get you so how could i fix it so that the d and h arguments are passed through the getType function in order for the area to be calculated properly

Comment: easy bro change your function prototype to this double getType(double d, double h);